# tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor() to numpy array

Tags: numpy, data, tensorflow

Estoy tratando de aplicar deformaciones elásticas para el aumento de datos usando:
[Elastic Transform for Data Augmentation](https://www.kaggle.com/bguberfain/elastic-transform-for-data-augmentation)

Usando openCV necesito las imágenes como una matriz numpy, cargar imágenes individuales funciona, pero en un dataset de tensorflow las imágenes tienen el formato *tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor ()*

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tr_urls[:10])
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_train_image,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Me gustaría saber cómo transformarlo en una matriz numpy usando **Tensorflow 2.0**

Comment: creo que esta resuelta aqui: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow) Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Cada uno de los elementos de train_dataset son del tipo:

```
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Según Tensorflow (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics) puedes convertir un Tensor a numpy array con la siguiente función:

```
print("The .numpy() method explicitly converts a Tensor to a numpy array")
print(tensor.numpy())
```